# Not able to update the version of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am facing the below error while running the code for LinearClassifier in tensorflow.

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.estimator.estimator_lib' has no attribute 'LinearRegressor'

My current version for tensorflow is 1.2.1. I tried to update the version of the package from ANACONDA environment, its not showing for an upgrade.

I tried to upgrade it from command prompt by using below command, it is successfully updating the package however it is not reflecting to the actual library when I am using it.

pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.3.0

FYI, I am using Jupyter Notebook and have created a separate environment for tensorflow.

Please let me know if I have missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

If your command `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`compiles, then your version of tensorflow should be the newest. However you should restart your notebook. Also, as you said that you are using anaconda. You can also install and upgrade tensorflow as follows:

```
 conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow  # to install
 conda upgrade -c conda-forge tensorflow  # to upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work. Check if you are using any environment but you are not updating the tensorflow version ***within the environment***.

Also, please restart the notebook after saving it and run the cells and try. That should work.

Verify in the notebook : run - `print(tf.__version__)`. Please mark the answer if it resolves.